# AudioRecord using bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, audio-recording

Im working on app which records audio from microphone and calculates frequency.
For input Im using:

```
recorder = new AudioRecord (AudioSource.MIC,8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,bufferSize);
```

When bluetooth headset is connected to phone I need to record from headset microphone, but at the moment app is using phone mic.

I have searched for answer and I havent seen concrete one.
Should I use AudioManager.startBluetoothSco() somehow?

Comment: HI, AlarMa, Do you resolve it by now? I encounter this too and wish that you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Hi were you able to find a solution for this?